# displaying data coming from createView

Tags: python, django

I have this code that extracts image from user posted url. I don't get any errors, but I'm not sure how to display the extracted image to my index.html. 
Here;s my views.py

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        # any manual settings go here
        self.object.moderator = self.request.user
        url = self.request.GET.get('url', False)
        if url:
            image = extract(url)
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):       
        return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here I have image = extract(url) 
extract method is coming from media.py.
Because I don't get any error, I'm assuming at least syntax is right. 
Now I want to display that image to my index.html. 
I thought post.image would do the job, but nothing shows up.

Here;s my media.py

```
import json
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request
from goose import Goose

def get_content(url):
    """This function is intended to return content from url.
    :param url: URL to get content
    :return: The response from url
    """
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': "Magic Browser"})
    response = urllib2.Request.urlopen(req).read()
    return response 


def extract(url):
    url = get_content(url)
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
    return json.dumps(resposne)
```

my models.py just in case

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = FroalaField()
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default= 1)

    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've extracted the URL from the request data and retrieved the image, but you haven't done anything with it at all. I guess you need to save it somewhere in the Post object.

Comment: thanks Daniel, pardon my english but that's what I was asking actually. I'm not sure how to display that image to index.html. Not sure what my next step is, I tried post.image but didn't work...not sure where to or how to save them

Comment: because I tried post.image and it didn't show, I thought my media.py is wrong but I don't see any error, maybe the way I treid to display is wrong//

Comment: But the problem is not in displaying, it is in *saving*. You call extract_image but then *throw away* the result. You need to actually save it somewhere.

Comment: so saving comes first then displaying?, I followed the tutorial here https://blog.openshift.com/day-16-goose-extractor-an-article-extractor-that-just-works/ and they didn't save it, so I thought i don't have to. How do I save them?

Comment: But can you not see that that tutorial is doing something completely different from you? It is accepting a URL and displaying the image from that URL immediately. You're accepting a bunch of data including a URL, saving most of that data into a "Post" object, redirecting to another page, then loading the Post data and sending it to the template. Surely you realise that in amongst that you will need to save the image data as well so that it can be retrieved?

Comment: ok, how do I save that image?  I mean I know how to save user posted image but how do save the image that is extract(url)?

Comment: btw, I'm doing something really similar with the tutorial. I realize I have to save the image now

Comment: So do I save that image in the model and display that? if I were to use thumbnail, now is the time right?....hmm do you mind showing me how I should do it....or is it too much..... still the original question:)